# Prove that $\operatorname{cov}\left[x - E(x\mid y), E(x\mid y)\right] = 0$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, covariance

Contents below are what I have done.

\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}\left[E(x\mid y),x - E(x\mid y)\right] &= E[xE(x\mid y)] - E(E^2(x\mid y)) - E(x)E(x - E(x\mid y))
\\&=E\left[xE(x\mid y)\right] - E(E^2(x\mid y)) - E(x) [E(x) - E(x)] 
\\&= E\left[xE(x\mid y)\right] - E(E^2(x\mid y))
\end{align}

and then I don't know how to deal with this equation. Please tell me how to do next and the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditioning on $y$ we get $E[x(E(x|y)]=E(E(x(E(X|y)|y)))$. But $E(x(E(X|y)|y))=E((E(x|y)(E(x|y))=E[(E(x|y)]^{2}$. Just use this in the first line of your proof.

Comment: I agree that $E[xE(x|y)] = E(E[xE(x|y)]|y)$. But in your next step, the condition $y$ belongs to the outside expectation, not the second...... so I cannot understand how you deal with $E(E[xE(x|y)]|y)$

Comment: Since $E(x|y)$ is already measurable w.r.t, $y$ you can pull it out: $E(xz|y)=zE(x|y)$ if $z$ is measurable w.r.t. $y$. Take $z=E(x|y)$ in this . @StorageGuard.Osaka

Comment: I know it, but $ E(E[xE(x|y)]|y)$ is the conditional expectation of $E[xE(x|y)]$ w.r.t $y$. Of course I know E(x|y) is a random variable depending on $y$, you mean...... with the condition of $y$, $E(x|y)$ in $E[xE(x|y)]$ can be regarded constant?.@Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: Yes, you can regard it as  constant and pull it out. That is one of the basic properties of conditional expectation. @StorageGuard.Osaka

Comment: Thank you, friend. Now I can deal with it. @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: Some of your brackets are unpaired.